# Proper way to maintain azure resource manager template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have arm template to recreate resource group with resources and their settings. This works fine.

**Use case:**

Some developer goes to azure portal and update some settings for some resource. Is there a way how to get exact changes that can be applied to my template to take these changes in effect? (Update template in source control)

If I go to automation script in resource group I can see all resources but my template in source control is different (parameters, conditions, variables, multiple templates linked together ...). I can't see on first look what changes were done and I can't use any diff.

Maybe I missed completely something but how are you solving this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to see any changes to resources by comparing templates from within the portal. Best practice is to always use ARM templates (and CI/CD pipelines) to deploy ARM templates to provision resources. Keep these ARM templates under source control to track them.

Further than that, I think you have two main options to track these changes:

1) You can use the [Azure Activity Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-logs-overview) to track the changes. The Azure Activity Log is a subscription log that provides insight into subscription-level events that have occurred in Azure. This includes a range of data, from Azure Resource Manager operational data to updates on Service Health events.

2) Write a little intelligent code against the Management Plane API. A good starting point is https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions. You could write a little extract that pulls all your resources out daily and commits them to a git repo. This will only update for changes to templates. You can then analyse the delta as or when you need.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Interesting idea with point 2. Anyway the template itself must simply be maintained manually, right? I mean easy way is that developer will simply update template when he modifies something in portal but I was really curious whether there is some tool that can simplify that.

Comment: Not that I know of and certainly no free option, there may be in some product. It would be nice if Microsoft spent a bit more time on the template engine in the portal and link it to git/hub or DevOps Repos some how and allowed one to do a bit of round tripping.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptionally, the developer should never 'go[es] to azure portal and update some settings for some resource', except for his own development / unit testing work. He then should produce an updated ARM template for deployment in the TST etc environments, and document his unit-tested changes with the new template. If his update collides with your resources in TST he will probably come to you to explain his changes, and discuss the resolution.